# jQuery sticky footer when not in view

Tags: jquery, css, sticky-footer

Another sticky footer question i'm afraid. Can't quite seem to find a suitable method of what Im trying to achieve.

I have a footer which is currently position relative at the bottom of a dynamic height middle container.

When the window becomes smaller than the bottom of the footer I need the footer to be absolutely positioned to the bottom of the window and slightly transparent.

I currently have this but can't seem to get it working:

```
var footer = $('footer');
var start = $(footer).offset().top;

$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    var pos = $(window).height();
    $(footer).css('position',((pos)<start) ? 'relative' : 'absolute');
    $(footer).css('bottom',((pos)<start) ? '0px' : '');
});
```

Please help.

Thanks guys

Comment: can you jsfiddle it? why not use a css sticky footer?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle example of what im trying to do. I want the red footer to be positioned absolutely to bottom when not in view: http://jsfiddle.net/tc7p3/1/

Comment: Managed to get this working how i wanted it: http://jsfiddle.net/tc7p3/4/ If there's a way to improve it then please suggest a better way. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should probably add this as a answer:

Managed to get this working how i wanted it: jsfiddle.net/tc7p3/4 If there's a way to improve it then please suggest a better way. thanks